# How Implement ACL In ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am new new ROR and i am using Ruby 1.9.2 & Rails 3.

My Question is

How to implement ACL in ROR? Jusi like cakephp.

cakephp provide

- ACO Database tabel for controller and his action.
- ARO Database tabel for usera and his group.
- ACO_ARO Database tabel for permission.

I want this type of dynamicall, ACL (Permission) Module in ROR.

Please help.

Comment: We use [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) gem in our projects.

Comment: we use devise for auth and have created our own scopes throughout the app; we use `before_action` in our controllers and have an endpoint for the angular app to check permissions. CanCan looks nice to me. I am a little concerned about its implementation as a service to check auth for frontend apps